# Fade content in/out on click with delay

Tags: javascript, fadein, fade, tumblr, fadeout

In the [Tumblr](http://phillypraxis.tumblr.com/) theme I'm building, I've managed to fade posts in shortly after the background fades in, using just CSS. However, I think it looks weird for posts to fade in but just blink out. I found Javascript to handle fading the posts in and out but the background fade in is necessarily delayed a bit. I want the javascript fade in of the posts to occur AFTER the background fades in, but I can't seem to effectively delay that animation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".posts").css("display", "none");

$(".posts").fadeIn(1000);

$("a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    linkLocation = this.href;
    $(".posts").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);     
});

function redirectPage() {
    window.location = linkLocation;
}
});
</script>
```

How would I delay the fadeIn for x seconds?

UPDATE (19 August 2012): I still haven't figured out how to delay the Javascript animation for more than 1 second, BUT I found that just allowing CSS to handle the fade in works fine. I didn't even remove the javascript command to fadeIN. The CSS simply overrides it I guess. It effectively solved my problem, on the surface at least.

Comment: How about `$(".posts").delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried that, and I think it worked, but it's not long enough. I need 3, maybe 5 seconds, and it seems to crap out after 1000ms...Maybe a SERIES of delays? o_o

UPDATE: Adding 4 1000ms delays didn't work. The posts simply didn't fade in at all.

Comment: Just pick a larger number for the delay like this: `.delay(10000)`.  It can be as large a number as you need.  It does not "crap out" with larger numbers.

Comment: I'm not actually a programmer, more of an enthusiast, but SOMETHING went wrong. Whenever I set the value higher than 1000, the posts just never showed at all. Instead of 3000 delaying it for 3 seconds, it was effectively delaying it forever it seems.